# kendo grid custom delete not persisting to datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I simply want to use my own workflow for deleting a record from my grid. Is this not the proper way to do it via Javascript? The function below removes the row but refreshing the page shows the row was not actually deleted from the datasource and I do not see any requests sent in the network tab of Chrome. I should add that I am able to obtain a reference to the grid and the dataItem perfectly.

```
 function delete(e) {

                var $tr = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"),
                    grid = this,
                    dataItem = grid.dataItem($tr),
                    id = $tr.attr(kendo.attr("uid")),
                    model = grid.dataSource.getByUid(id);

                e.preventDefault();           

                grid.dataSource.remove(model);
                grid.dataSource.sync();
    }
```

Edit - Here is how my datasource is defined:

```
$scope.contacts = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                update: {
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: apiUrl,
                    type: "DELETE"
                },
                create: {
                    url: apiUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10
        });
```

Comment: How is `DataSource.transport` defined?

Comment: @OnaBai: I have edited my post to include the declaration of my datasource.

Comment: In your `delete` function, `dataItem` and `model` should be the same. It should be enough getting `dataItem` and then `grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);` but this should not make any difference and I don't see anything wrong with your transport definition ... :-(

Comment: Hmm yeah weird. I would at least be able to figure out what was wrong if I could see some traffic in my network pane in Chrome, but there is nothing.

Comment: having the same problem too... i can see the request on read but on delete there is nothing, It seems that destroy is not triggered, i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

I found something and I dont know if it works in your side.
I needed to add this line in my kendo.datasource

```
    schema: { 
             model:{id:"id"}
        }
```

and trigger like this

```
     data_source_inspection.remove(selected.data);
     data_source_inspection.sync();
```

this works for me.